# Why a href link in an svg is working on Firefox (on Ubuntu) but not on Safari on IOS

Tags: html, svg, safari, href, mobile-safari

Here is a MWE.

There are 2 links (at the bottom) to the same reference (at the top).
One link not in a svg, the other one in a svg.

I'm expecting both of them to have the same effect.
They appear to do so on my Firefox.
But on an IPhone, the svg link doesn't do anything. Why?

I tried some tricks found on the internet, but nothing worked.
I have the feeling that Safari is lost, and that I could tell it more to help it.
But what can I do?
Is there some simple workaround?
And I would expect this workaround to work even if the html page is local.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>my title</title>
</head>
<div id="my_ref">
    my reference
</div>

ZZZZ
<br>
ZZZZ
<br>
ZZZZ
<br>
ZZZZ
<br>
ZZZZ
<br>
ZZZZ
<br>
ZZZZ
<br>
ZZZZ
<br>
ZZZZ
<br>
ZZZZ
<br>
ZZZZ
<br>
ZZZZ
<br>
ZZZZ
<br>
ZZZZ
<br>
ZZZZ
<br>
ZZZZ
<br>
ZZZZ
<br>
ZZZZ
<br>
ZZZZ
<br>
ZZZZ
<br>
ZZZZ
<br>
ZZZZ
<br>
ZZZZ
<br>
ZZZZ
<br>
ZZZZ
<br>
ZZZZ
<br>
ZZZZ
<br>
ZZZZ
<br>
ZZZZ
<br>
ZZZZ
<br>
ZZZZ
<br>
ZZZZ
<br>
ZZZZ
<br>
ZZZZ
<br>
ZZZZ
<br>
ZZZZ
<br>
ZZZZ
<br>
ZZZZ
<br>
ZZZZ
<br>
ZZZZ
<br>
ZZZZ
<br>

<a href="#my_ref">link to my reference outside of svg</a>

<br>

<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" width="500" height="500">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="500" height="500" style="fill:yellow"/>
  <a href="#my_ref"> <text x="10%" y="50%">(link to my reference inside svg)</text></a>
</svg>


</html>
```

EDIT 1:
My MWE was too minimal!
The suggested solution works for my MWE, but not for my real web page.

I'm putting a second MWE, closer to my real web page (something like the Wordle page, with a menu, and some modal pages for help, statistics, etc.).

How can I make this MWE work on Safari ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>my title</title>
    
    <style> 
    
        .modal-window {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        pointer-events: none;
        }
        
        .modal-window:target {
        opacity: 1;
        pointer-events: auto;
        }
        
        .modal-window > div {
        max-width: 95vw;
        max-width: 600px;
        max-height: 85vh;
        position: relative;
        margin: 10% auto;
        padding: 2rem;
        background: lightgray;
        }
        
        
        .modal-close {
        color: red;
        line-height: 50px;
        font-size: 80%;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        text-align: center;
        top: 0;
        width: 70px;
        text-decoration: none;
        }
        
        
        body {
        font-size: 32px;
        height: 100vh;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        }
        
        .for_svg
        {
            max-height: 50vh;
        }
    
    </style>
    
</head>

<body>
    <div id="open-modal" class="modal-window">
        <div>
            <a href="#tftyjfjfjhf" title="Close" class="modal-close">&times;</a>
            MODAL INFO
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="#open-modal">link outside svg</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <svg class="for_svg" viewBox="0 0 400 400" >
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="400" height="400" style="fill:yellow"/>
            <a href="#open-modal"><text x="10%" y="50%">link inside svg</text></a>
        </svg>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use the attribute `name` instead of `id` for defining anchors. Also, don’t use `<div>` but `<a>`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it works on my MWE, but not on my real web page.
I put another MWE, with the same problem on Safari; a MWE closer to my real web page (that I can't disclose here).

Comment: then your mwe is not representative for the issue. however, the question clearly asks how to bring the mwe to work properly. i can’t help you with anything i am not even allowed to see

Comment: put an `<a name="open-modal"></a>` in front of your div element. however, if it’s absolutely positioned you may have trouble getting it to work properly. Or put it as the first child of your div element. you need to play around a bit

Comment: On Safari on IOS, it works neither with `<a name="open-modal"></a>` in front of my div element or as the first child of the div.
(when I click on the 2nd link, it doesn't open)
These work (well) as the MWE 2 on Firefox and Chromium on Ubuntu.

Comment: Is there a way to write something explicit like href="MY_CURRENT_PAGE#open-modal"?
I saw people doing a workaround on a similar bug with internet domains name (like explained there: https://jenandersondigital.com/blog/safari-anchor-tag-not-working/), but not for a no-name page like mine.
The hack would then be to add a slash before the hash.

Comment: test it out? nothing in your question said iOS by the way. safari is available for window and os x as well (no idea about linux so far)

Comment: I wrote Safari on the title, and IPhone in my question, but I should have written it in the title; But Safari isn't available for Windows anymore. And not Linux of course...
And sorry, I don't understand "test it out" here. Do you mean, to test things like href="/#open-modal" or href="./#open-modal"? I did. Doesn't work (points to my files...).